# Problem with GRUB not being on Hard Disk

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I have just done an install of Ubuntu 12.04 on a new PC with no OS from a USB but the GRUB has not installed onto the Hard Disk but onto Flash, how do I correct this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually install GRUB onto a device if it was installed to the wrong place by issuing

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Quoted: However if the above doen`t make it possible to boot the OS you can use "Rescue a broken system" at the USB drive's startup menu to install GRUB.

[image]

Follow the prompts to start up your system, selecting the hard disk partition when requested. The “Enter rescue mode” screen appears which provides options to mount your system. Your broken system will be mounted and made accessible with a command line interface. You can then use command line operations and editors to fix configuration files. If you need to reinstall the boot loader, you can choose the “Reinstall GRUB boot loader” entry.

[image]

Source: [Super User: Ubuntu Server installed from USB puts GRUB on the USB drive instead of the hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/176050/ubuntu-server-installed-from-usb-putsgrub-on-theusb-drive-instead-of-the-hard)

Comment: Excellent, @Mitch, this is a better idea than the "go `chroot` it" I (and some other veterans) may be inclined to suggest!